# Hibernate SubQuery Bug? Unexpected End of Subtree

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been debugging a query and have distilled it down to a simple one that I think should work in Hibernate's HqL as it is valid in SQL.

The queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT 1)
```

and

```
SELECT (SELECT 1), (SELECT 2)
```

Should, in my opinion, both be valid and I'm ready to report as a defect in Hibernate, but wanted to vet it first here.

When I run these in Hibernate, I get:

```
3585 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
```

I'm running Hibernate 3.6.0.Final.

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are missing an opining paranthese in this statement: SELECT (SELECT 1), )SELECT 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a JIRA for this:

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7182